# How can i compare two columns in two different rows in python

Tags: python, csv

I want to go through each line of the a csv file and compare to see if the first field of line 1 is same as first field of next line and so on. If it finds a match then i would like ignore those two lines that contains the same fields and keep the lines where there is no match

Here is an example dataset (no_dup.txt)

```
Ac_Gene_ID  M_Gene_ID
ENSGMOG00000015632  ENSORLG00000010573
ENSGMOG00000015632  ENSORLG00000010585
ENSGMOG00000003747  ENSORLG00000006947
ENSGMOG00000003748  ENSORLG00000004636
```

Basically i want to exclude line 1 and 2 since they contains the same fields (ENSGMOG00000015632) and keep lines 3 and 4

Here is the code i have tried but couldn't finish it

```
prev = None

with open("no_dup.txt", 'r') as fh_in:
    for line in fh_in:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.startswith("E"):
            line1 = line.split()
            print "initial gene =", line1[0]
            if prev is not None or prev!= line1[0]:
                prev = line1[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a clean way of doing this would be to make a map of each entry -> list of lines.

```
entries = {}
with open('no_dup.txt', 'r') as fh_in:
    for line in fg_in:
        entry = line.split()[0]
        if entry in entries:
            entries[entry].append(line)
        else:
            entries[entry] = [line]
for matches in entries.iteritems():
    if len(matches) == 1:
        print matches[0]
```

You should note that this will NOT preserve the order of entries.

Comment: It is a good usecase for [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: How do i get the whole row for the `entry` ?

Comment: Oh wow, yeah that doesn't cover it. I'll edit my answer, but I'd instead change the dict value to be a list of lines.

Answer (score 0):

Your start looks good:

```
def filter_dups(iterable):
      prev = None
      for line in iterable:
          if line.startswith("E"):
              if prev.split(None, 1)[0] == line.split(None, 1)[0]:
                  prev = None
              else:
                  if prev is not None:
                      yield prev
                  else:
                      prev = line
          else:
              yield line
              prev = None
      if prev is not None:
          yield prev

  with open("no_dup.txt", 'r') as fh_in:
      with open("no_dup_out.txt", 'r') as fh_out:
          fh_out.writelines(filter_dups(fh_in))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
with open('a.txt','r') as inputFile:
   lines = inputFile.readlines()

prev = lines[0]

for i in range(1, len(lines)):
   cur = lines[i]
   if prev.split()[0] != cur.split()[0]:
      print prev.strip()
   prev = cur

print lines[-1].strip()
```

Input:

```
ENSGMOG00000015632  ENSORLG00000010573
ENSGMOG00000015632  ENSORLG00000010585
ENSGMOG00000003747  ENSORLG00000006947
ENSGMOG00000003748  ENSORLG00000004636
```

Output:

```
ENSGMOG00000015632  ENSORLG00000010585
ENSGMOG00000003747  ENSORLG00000006947
ENSGMOG00000003748  ENSORLG00000004636
```

Comment: In your output i don't want this line `ENSGMOG00000015632  ENSORLG00000010585` but only the other two lines